# Create Python virtual environment with venv using existing pyvenv.cfg

Tags: python, python-venv

Is it possible to create a Python virtual environment with `venv` using an *existing* `pyvenv.cfg`? For example, something like:

```
$ python3 -m venv --use-cfg=./pyvenv.cfg /path/to/new/enviroment
```

Comment: Could you comment on your intended use case / why you want to replicate the settings in an existing `pyvenv.cfg`? There's a chance there's a simpler approach to get what you need

Comment: As far as I know, there is no tool that provides this. But it should be easy to do it yourself. -- This is a good description of virtual environments: https://snarky.ca/how-virtual-environments-work/